# echo the update field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am updating a row in the mysql table. After updating the row, I want to show the user the information such as "This information is updated now"

SO this is my code:

```
   $result->$mysqli->query("UPDATE table SET status ="updated" WHERE id = '$id'");
   if($result->num_rows > 0) {
   ///I WANT TO ECHO/ALERT THE UPDATE INFORMATION HERE
   }
```

Thanks in advance:

Comment: If the id is unique you can use the $id to tell which element was updated (even with other query)

Comment: You can do another select after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not `->num_rows` since you didn't select any rows so it doesn't make sense to know how many rows did it yield. If you wan't to know if it did make an update on a row, use `affected_rows`:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET status = 'updated' WHERE id = ?";
$update = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$update->bind_param('s', $id);
$update->execute();

if($update->affected_rows > 0) {
    echo 'yeah it updated that row!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQLi query with update query returns FALSE on failure and TRUE on success.
So, basically, if $result is true then it has been updated. You can just echo "Success".

```
$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE table SET status ="updated" WHERE id = '$id'");
if ($result) 
{
    echo "Success";
}
```

If you need to write which data has been changed you need to add SELECT queries before and\or after UPDATE query and output it.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the number of updated rows for example:

```
$result->$mysqli->query("UPDATE table SET status ="updated" WHERE id = '$id'");
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php